# Spfx source files from spkg

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework, typescript

Inlost my source file of spfx webpart. I only have spkg package can i extract source field from spkg please help mei it's urgent

Answer (score 3):

The sppkg file is actually a zip archive that you can extract, but it contains the compiled and minified js files, not the source typescript files.

Comment: Any way to  to change minified J's file to  typescript I need to change some logic in my webpart any help

Comment: Not really... Maybe you can try some recovery tool to get back your source files?